# Simple sql string correction

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 tables in my sqlite3 database. Can someone help me with the sql command below:

`tbltrans`:

```
transid |  transdate | discountpercentage | Bank
12345     10/09/2011     5                  20.00
```

`tbltrans2`:

```
transid   |   itemnr   |price | btwpercentage | qty
12345         205        10.11        12        5
12345         302        15.00        6         7
12345         501        20.00        21        3
```

My first question is:

1. I want to get a query table with total amount of sale for each transid's and calculated cash, like:

   ```
   Select
       Sum(tbltrans2.qty * tbltrans2.price) as TotalAmount,
       (Totalamount - tbltrans.Bank) as Cash
   where 
       tbltrans.transid = tbltrans2.transid 
       and transdate = '10/09/12'
   ```

   Can someone please correct this SQL statement ?

**-- This question below is already solved --**

So, can anyone correct my sql code to work with this table layout:

```
select 
    sum(price * qty - (price * qty) * (tbltrans.discountpercentage / 100)  
from 
    tbltrans2 
where 
    btwpercentage = 6) as total6 ,
  sum(price * qty - (price*qty)*(tbltrans.discountpercentage /100) from tbltrans2 where btwpercentage =12) as total12,
sum(price * qty - (price*qty)*(tbltrans.discountpercentage /100) from tbltrans2 where btwpercentage =21) as total21
 where transdate = date('10/09/2011')
```

Comment: are you getting an error message?

Comment: What is your required output?

Comment: We can't help you fix it if you don't tell us what is wrong and what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes, maybe its because I haven't specified enough information in tbltrans.discountpercentage..
I think it should be something like select discountpercentage from tbltrans where transid = '12345' but I don't actually know how to impliment this in this statement.

Comment: I need to get sum of 3 different btwtypes
*btw = VAT or tax percentage

Comment: Show the output that you want to get from your example.

Comment: I  want to get the sum by calculating those fields. For example: If I have one row in tbltrans with price = 100 , qty= 10 btwpercentage=6 and in tbltrans i have the field with same transid with discountper =10 then I should get 900 as total6
 Total6 Total12 Total21
950 950 950

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to join the tables and use something like this:

```
select 
  sum(case when t2.btwpercentage =6 then
        t2.price * t2.qty - (t2.price * t2.qty* t1.discountpercentage /100) end) Total6,
  sum(case when t2.btwpercentage =12 then
        t2.price * t2.qty - (t2.price * t2.qty* t1.discountpercentage /100) end) Total12,
  sum(case when t2.btwpercentage =21 then
        t2.price * t2.qty - (t2.price * t2.qty* t1.discountpercentage /100) end) Total21
from tbltrans t1
left join tbltrans2 t2
  on t1.transid = t2.transid
where transdate = date('10/09/2011')
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/1c0f5/1)

Based on your comments, you can also use:

```
select count(t1.transid) Total,
  sum(case when t2.btwpercentage =6 then
        t2.price * t2.qty - (t2.price * t2.qty* t1.discountpercentage /100) end) Total6,
  sum(case when t2.btwpercentage =12 then
        t2.price * t2.qty - (t2.price * t2.qty* t1.discountpercentage /100) end) Total12,
  sum(case when t2.btwpercentage =21 then
        t2.price * t2.qty - (t2.price * t2.qty* t1.discountpercentage /100) end) Total21
from tbltrans t1
left join tbltrans2 t2
  on t1.transid = t2.transid
where transdate = date('10/09/2011')
```

Comment: I couldn't make it work with my vb application. I tried changing double quote(") with single (') to make it work with vb.net, but still no luck. Here is my file: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/11189181/POS.s3db

Comment: You probably can remove the quotes (single/double) they were placed by  the SQL Fiddle.

Comment: I did it, but I still couldn't get anything as a output.

Comment: yes it did work in my database. 
Do I get the output as row or a table?
Maybe its a silly question but I have very low knowledge in programming.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not a vb person so I can't help on that question.  If you have code that is not working to display the result from this query, then my suggestion would be to ask another question. You will then get answers from people who know that area.

Comment: sorry to bother you again, but how do I use count on tbltrans on same statement?

Comment: what kind of count? What do you want to count?

Comment: Numbers of records in tbltrans with the transdate that is provided.

Comment: is it possible to handle the dbnull value within the statement?

Comment: @VijayDezzods you should probably post another question as I am not sure

Comment: What i just want to know is, when i get dbnull or null value for some statement, my programme gives me error. THERE is a way to fix this in the programme but wanted to know if there is any fix within the statement. '0' instead of null value for example..thanks

Comment: Isn't is possible to do something like this?
ifnull(Total6,0)

Comment: Hello Mr. @blufeet,
Thanks for helping with my question.
Can you please correct my first statement aswell?

Comment: Instead of editing your question here, you should post a new question.

Comment: Here is my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033043/simply-query-with-calculated-fields

Answer (score 1):

If you want your query to work basically as written, then you need to add a `from` clause:

```
Select 
sum(price * qty - (price*qty)*(tbltrans.discountpercentage /100) from tbltrans2 where btwpercentage =6) as total6 ,
 sum(price * qty - (price*qty)*(tbltrans.discountpercentage /100) from tbltrans2 where btwpercentage =12) as total12,
sum(price * qty - (price*qty)*(tbltrans.discountpercentage /100) from tbltrans2 where btwpercentage =21) as total21
from tbltrans
 where transdate = date('10/09/2011')
```

However, bluefeet provides a somewhat cleaner version, although I would write the select logic as:

```
sum(case when t2."btwpercentage" =6
         then  t2."price"*t2."qty" * (1 - t1."discountpercentage" /100.0)
     end) Total6,
```