# Simply query with calculated fields

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 2 tables in my sqlite3 database. Can someone help me with the sql command below:

tbltrans:

```
transid |  transdate | discountpercentage | Bank
12345     10/09/2011     5                  20.00
```

tbltrans2:

```
transid   |   itemnr   |price | btwpercentage | qty
12345         205        10.11        12        5
12345         302        15.00        6         7
12345         501        20.00        21        3
```

SO I want to get a query table with total amount of sale for each transid's and calculated cash column, Like:

```
Select
Sum(tbltrans2.qty * tbltrans2.price) as TotalAmount,
(Totalamount - tbltrans.Bank) as Cash
where 
tbltrans.transid = tbltrans2.transid and transdate = '10/09/12'
```

Can someone please correct this sql satement ?

Comment: You are missing the "From" statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Select
Sum(ifnull((tbltrans2.qty * tbltrans2.price),0))-tbltrans.Bank as cash
from tbltrans,tbltrans2
where 
tbltrans.transid = tbltrans2.transid and tbltrans.transdate = '10/09/12'
group by tbltrans.transid
```

try this

If you want to select total amount also then include this in 
select,

```
Sum(ifnull((tbltrans2.qty * tbltrans2.price),0)) as TotalAmount
```

Comment: Gives an error :
'Query Error: near "from": syntax error Unable to execute statement'

Comment: again got a error. no such function **nv**
I'm working on sqlite3

Comment: Yes man, thanks :)
and I get the values as irrational number, is there any way to get them as double?

Comment: I get 8.881784797e-16 but the table datas are different.